# When should I use multiple event names vs different event emitters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

Which is the better way to use events?

A)

```
var doorBell = new events.EventEmitter()
var light = new events.EventEmitter()

doorBell.emit('open')
light.emit('on')
doorBell.on('open', function(){
    console.log('The door is open!');
});
light.on('on', function(){
    console.log('The lights are on');
});
```

B)

```
var house = new events.EventEmitter()

house.emit('doorOpen')
house.emit('lightOn')
house.on('doorOpen', function(){
  console.log('The door is open!');
});
house.on('lightOn', function(){
  console.log('The lights are on');
});
```

I'm wondering if there is any kind of difference between the two, performance wise or any difference really ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `emitt` should be `emit`...

Comment: Right but not really the issue, thanks anyway I guess ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda dislike giving this answer, but I'd say *it depends*.

As you know, both variants work, so it's just a matter of preference. Objects hide complexity, and events should be used keeping that idea in mind. In your example I think it would be perfectly fine to use one *house* object that would emit events for turning on the lights, and ringing the doorbell.

As you might foresee, there will be a point at which the addition of events will get messy. So you have to decide for yourself where the boundary lies of whether a certain event belongs to the scope of a certain object.